# how to use JavaScript variable in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I have an onClick event in my `test.php` file:

```
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
   <tr><td onclick="testfun(".$i.")"></td></tr>
```

**Script**:

```
<script>
    function  testfun(i)
        return i;
<script>
```

Now I want to use that `$i` in PHP to see on which `<tr>` the mouse is clicked on so I can perform my other functionalities in the PHP file. e.g

```
<?php echo $i?>
```

How can I do that? I saw some AJAX tutorials but I didn't get how its gonna work on my code.

Comment: what will do after you get the value in `php`? You just simply wanted to display which one was clicked ?

Comment: yeah you can say that.
Once I print it then I also able to do other functionalities that i want

Comment: No, you have to be clear. You just wanted to show or will re-use it later in you `php` code .You need to specify the purpose of that variable. Because, solution will differ

Comment: actually that $i variable is used for the dates in Attendance system 1-30 and once someone clicked on a td  then he can apply for a holiday or he can also edit the previous submission on the same section so i just want that day on which he clicked so I can loop through the variable or object(that i already have in this file) and onl prints the data for that day.

Comment: I'm still not clear what are you trying to achieve. But, I will post work around solution.

Comment: I have posted the answer, let me know, whether that is what you expects ?

Comment: hmm ok, 
simply just tell me how  can I convert a javascript variable to php.
or return a js value to php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152487/discussion-between-aihtsham-ali-and-ravi).

Answer (score 0):

in your html add this to your javascript

```
        $('#clickhere').click(function(){
           //get value here from your function
           // do the ajax
           $.ajax({
                url: "path/of/your/php/file.php",
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: value_that_you_fetch,  
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(data){
                    // do something here
                }
            });
        });
```

and don't forget to add a jquery CDN

and in your file.php

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['value_that_you_fetch'];
```

the rest is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

your **php** code should be like this

```
<?php 
    for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){
?>
       <tr><td onclick="testfun(<?php echo $i ?>)"></td></tr>
<?php } ?>
```

and **javascript** code

```
<script>
       function  testfun(i){
            return i;
       }

 <script>
```

Comment: brother I'm not asking about the code correction. i'm asking how can i get a value from js back to php

Comment: you can `console.log(i)` or `alert(i)` in `testfun` function in js to get value of `$i` from **php** in **js** @aihtsham ali

Comment: I know that what i want is to convert a JS variable to PHP

Comment: you can use **jquery ajax** to pass **JS** variable to **PHP** file

Answer (score 0):

So, if this is your onClick event handler:

```
  function  testfun(i){
    return i;
  }
```

The quickest way to get on to the next step is to have it be something like:

```
  function  testfun(i){
    $.ajax( {
      url: "/ajaxtest.php?i=" + i,
      type: 'GET',
      // ... other options depend on what you want returned.
    } );
  }
```

This is a deep rabbit hole your are looking down into here.